# Web Analytics Connector in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, developer, email-tracking

I have update WAC parameters in SFMC and sent a test email(Crated using ampscript and html) and added links in email like product Images links using redirect method of ampscript but after clicking on that emails **I am not able to see WAC parameters after clicking on that link.**

http://click.e.newwAccount.com/?qs=687bf70d37b5b0441f497cfb9dae8f6b1a95cdca48415f4e9c01c99a21ed92fd8213fa1072967f52878545479e02208e

Not able to see subscriberid and other paramters in links

Note:- WAC parameters are appended to each link to every email

Comment: so that is the wrapped link to provide link tracking. I would suggest taking that link to wheregoes and view when the WAC string is dropped

Comment: Open the link with network inspector open. Maybe your landingpage has rewrite rules in place stripping those GET parameters. As EazyE pointed out, you wont be seeing any parameters on that wrapped link but only on the resolved one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview an email using the subscriber preview option and then test it by clicking on the link to see if the link got updated and you have got everything on the link.